# Access violation reading location 0x00C4702C

Tags: c++, exception, memory, if-statement, for-loop

I have some problems with my code.

```
void gMenu_BP()
{
CLS // #define system("cls");
cout << "Ive opened my backpack and saw...\n\n";
cout << ":Name\t\tQuantity\t\tPrice\n\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(Items); i++)
    {
        try{
            if(Items[i].owd==1)
            {
                cout <<i+1<<">"<<Items[i].Name<<"\t"<<Items[i].q<<"\t\t\t"<<Items[i].price<<endl;
            }
        }
        catch(exception ex) {
            cout << "error";
        }
    }
    //cout<<"====================================================";
    cout <<"1.Use Item\n2.Remove Item\n3.Back to Journey";
    int volba01;
    cin >> volba01;

}
```

What it does, that it shows all objects with owner id 1. All of them will be written to the console. My problem is this:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00C3A2CA in Journey.exe: 
0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00C4702C.
```

Its just crashes even out of VC++. Note that I this worked perfectly, but then Ive started having problem with text rendering(one char per 80mil). Then Ive disabled few functions related to printf();
And then the error started throwing even here. Its like a virus or what. on exception it shows me VC++ output.c file and some other system files. I dont know what to do and moving to C# will be little hard.

EDIT:
Ok now it works. Ive changed for-loop header to

```
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(Items)/sizeof(player.Items[0]); i++)
```

Its a weird solution but works good.

Comment: Sounds like UB somewhere in your code

Comment: What is the type of `Items`.  At the least, the loop test should be `i < sizeof(Items)/sizeof(item_type)` whatever `item_type` is.  Also, what is output before the crash?

Comment: The output prints my items normally, then comes the crash. Items is defined from ItemData struct.

Comment: @ZaKlaus _'Items is defined from ItemData struct'_ Little joker you are, aren't you? How should we know what it is? Would you mind to show us?

Comment: Picking up a specific item is fine.  Item type would be better for style.

Comment: hmm.. why -1 when its working? Can I ask?

Comment: (And I'm guessing the dowvote was because you gave such a stupid response to the request to see how `items` was defined.)

Comment: Thanks for tip. I worked in C# all the time. Im newbie to C++.

Comment: Sorry but what response? If it sounds stupid, then sorry for my English. Im not English native.

Comment: Im just doing my Job. If I responded somehow bad tell it to me. I really dont know how it sounds.

Comment: "Items is defined from ItemData struct" -- that tells us exactly nothing.

Comment: I will edit it somehow: Items variable is instance of ItemData struct. Hope thats ok.

Comment: @HotLicks I didn't downvote at least, but s.o. might have felt attempted due to my comment.

Comment: No I know it wasnt you. Its ok. Its just a piece of code. I have better things to do.

Comment: Solution found, closed.

Comment: The thing to do next time would be to include in your listing the data declarations.  Eg, `ItemData[10] Items;` and `struct ItemData {...`.

Comment: Also note that standard C/C++/Java coding convention (everywhere but Microsoft) is to use Leading Capital Letters only for classes/structs.  Use leading lower-case letters for variables and method names.  You can biCapitalize within a variable/method name, however.

Comment: Thanks, I have solution for this already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Ive defined max. instances (elements) of struct Items.

```
 #define MAX_OBJECTS 20
```

my instance of struct Items:

```
 ItemData Items[MAX_OBJECTS];
```

Then changed for-loop header to:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < MAX_OBJECTS; i++)
```

Yes, very easy solution, worthless of posting a question.

Thanks anyone for help.

Hope Ive helped somebody with same problem.